# Recursion infinite loop that is making my code broken

Tags: java

My code is getting the stackOverflowError meaning there is something wrong with my recursion. Basically I am in an infinite loop and cannot figure out how to get this error to go away.

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getLines(int firstLine, int 
lastLine) {
        for(int i=firstLine; i<=lastLine; i++) {
          players.get(i).getAttributes();   
        }
   return getLines(firstLine, lastLine);              
}
```

I am trying to get my code to return an array of arrays. Or more simply an array of all of my player arrays

Comment: A key component of recursion is to have an ending point - you do not have one, if all cases you will recursively call `getLines`

Comment: The only way you're ending this method is by calling it again. You need to have another condition under which the method can end normally. Maybe you need to check at the beginning `if(firstLine == lastLine) {return immediately;}`

Comment: Share from where you are invoking this function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to increment firstLine while making the recursive call and also break the loop when `firstLine == lastLine`

Answer (score 0):

*I am trying to get my code to return an array of arrays. Or more simply an array of all of my player arrays*

If you want an array of arrays, you could do that with Java 8 Streams API (I'm assuming that your player class is called Player)

```
List<List<String>> arrayOfArrays = players.stream().map(Player::getAttributes).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And if you want an array of all of your player arrays:

```
List<String> array = players.stream().flatMap(player -> player.getAttributes().stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion needs a base condition.

What you are doing is calling the same function repeatedly. Thus there is no stopping condition for the recursive function.

```
return getLines(firstLine, lastLine);
```